# Decrementing an array and print a value if condition met

Tags: c, arrays, loops, absolute-value

I want to decrement a pointer to the last element of an array and check for the condition that if the value of the pointer was smaller than 5, do nothing and go to the next round of loop and if not, that is if the value is equal or bigger than 5, print the value. So, for the array in the example, I want only 6 to be printed, that is the first encounter of a value equal or bigger than 5. I tried the code below but while being compiled with no error, it doesn't print any value. I'd appreciate your comments on this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//The is a C program to decrement an array from the last element to the first. 
    int x[11] = {5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2}; 
    int *lastElem, count;
int main (void) {
    lastElem = &x[10];
    for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
        if (abs(*lastElem) < 5)
        continue;
        else 
        printf("%d\n", *lastElem--); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the comparisiopn is wrong because the elements are smaller than 5

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the absolute of values.

Comment: sorry I don't get what you want now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in your decrement logic. If the value is less than 5, you're missing the decremet.

check the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//The is a C programme to decrement an array from the last element to the first. 
    int x[11] = {5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2};
    int *lastElem, count;
int main (void) {
    lastElem = &x[10];
    for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
    {
        if (*lastElem >= 5)
            {
            printf("%d\n", *lastElem);
             break ;
             }
        lastElem--;
    }
return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:

As you modified your question to include the `absolute value` comparions, the changes are like below.

**<sup>Note : When making some major changes [which will change the behaviour and output] to the original question asked, do make a note of that, and if possible, mention the edit properly.</sup>**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//The is a C programme to decrement an array from the last element to the first. 
int x[11] = {5, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2};
int *lastElem, count;
int main (void) {
        lastElem = &x[10];
        for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
        {
                if ( abs(*lastElem) >= 5)
                {
                        printf("%d\n", *lastElem);
                        break;
                }
                lastElem--;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wanted the first occurence of the number greater than 4(6 in OP's case) to be printed and not all the numbers greater than 4

Comment: @coolguy I tried to point out yhe erroneous part. However,  will update the answer to accomodate that also.

Comment: Sorry, a question, if these numbers were float rather than integers, would the only change be in the printf statement, that is       `printf(%.2f\n", *lastElem);`

Comment: @homa that's true but there will be other side effects. `abs ()` operates only on integers, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: fabs() works to get the absolute value of floating numbers in c

Answer (score 3):

You never assign another address to `lastElem` than the inital value (that is the 10th element). Also, if you want to go backwards, set `count` to 10 and let it count to 0. In each loop you have to assign `&x[count]` to `lastElem` (or decrement it, as it is a pointer and the address will be decremented according to the object it points to).

Answer (score 1):

The line `printf("%d\n", *lastElem--);` is not always executed it is only executed when `abs(*lastElem) >= 5`. This is how you should do it

```
#include<stdio.h>

//The is a C programme to decrement an array from the last element to the first. 
int x[11] = {5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2}; 
int *lastElem, count, value;
int main (void) 
{
    lastElem = &x[10];
    for (count = 0; count < 11; count++)
    {
        value = *(lastElem--);
        if (value < 5)
            continue;
        printf("%d\n", value);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will do it with `continue`.

Comment: I exactly want this but this does not print any value, I don't understand!

Comment: Yes, but this prints both 6 and 5, but I want it to print the first encounter of the value equal or bigger than 5 and then stop the loop. So, something like the previous code and when found 6, just break the loop.

Comment: You say, you only want `6` to be printed, in that case you should change `if (*lastElem >= 5)` with `if (*lastElem > 5)`

Comment: Yes, but I really am curious why the previous code didn't work as I had thought of the loop with using 'continue'

Comment: @iharob , If you do that,then 5 won't be printed if the array had 5 instead of 6

Comment: @Cool Guy, he said he only wanted 6 to be printed.

Comment: @Homa, it did not work with `continue` because `continue` means you continue looping without executing the code following it.

Comment: @iharob, great, now I understand, thanks for your code!

Comment: @iharob , True. But I'm saying that your code won't work if the first element greater than 4 from the end is 5. And the next number greater than 4 will be printed,if any,provided that it isn't 5

Comment: @Cool Guy Are you sure it won't check it? Change the array and see!

Comment: Oh. Sorry .I became confused with `value = *(lastElem--);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the only correct code among presented here in other answers that does the task.:)

In fact you need a program that searches backward an alement of an array that satisfies a given condition. And if there is such an element then to output it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2 }; 
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    int *first = a, *last = a + N;

    while ( first != last && ( unsigned int )abs( *( last - 1 ) ) < 5 ) --last;

    if ( first != last ) printf( "%d\n", *--last );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
6
```

Below there is demonstrated a general approach for such tasks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * find_backward( const int a[], size_t n, int ( *predicate )( int ) )
{
    const int *first = a, *last = a + n;

    while ( first != last && !predicate( *( last -1 ) ) ) --last;

    return ( int * )last;
}

int is_greater_or_equal_to_5( int x )
{
    return 5 <= ( unsigned int )abs( x );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2 }; 
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );


    int *target = find_backward( a, N, is_greater_or_equal_to_5 );  

    if ( target != a ) printf( "%d\n", *--target );

    return 0;
}
```

Using this approach you can use any integer arrays (even with zero size) and any conditions that are set by means of predicates.

For example if you want to find the last element of an array that is divisible by 3 you can write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * find_backward( const int a[], size_t n, int ( *predicate )( int ) )
{
    const int *first = a, *last = a + n;

    while ( first != last && !predicate( *( last -1 ) ) ) --last;

    return ( int * )last;
}

int divisible_by_3( int x )
{
    return x % 3 == 0;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 6, -4, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -2 }; 
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );


    int *target = find_backward( a, N, divisible_by_3 );    

    if ( target != a ) printf( "%d\n", *--target );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3
```

Take into account that this function allows also to deal with constant arrays.:)